# Scraping data from html table, selecting rows with certain attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping information from the following website:
"http://www.mobygames.com/game/wheelman/view-moby-score". Here is my code

```
url_credit = "http://www.mobygames.com/game/wheelman/view-moby-score"
response = requests.get(url_credit, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", class_="reviewList table table-striped table-condensed table-hover").select('tr[valign="top"]')
for row in table[1:]:
    print(row)
    x = soup.select('td[class="left"]').get("colspan")
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
platform     total_votes rating_category score  total_score
PlayStation3 None        None            None   None
Windows      6           Acting          4.2    4.1
Windows      6           AI              3.7    4.1
Windows      6           Gameplay        4.0    4.1
```

The main problem is having platform name on the platform column for corresponding observations.
How could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the row which has a new platform, has 3 columns, while others have 2. You can use that to change the platform.

You can see that rows like *PlayStation* have a column (`<td>` tag) with `colspan="2" class="center"` attributes. Use this to handle cases like *PlayStation*.

Code:

```
url_credit = "http://www.mobygames.com/game/wheelman/view-moby-score"
response = requests.get(url_credit, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", class_="reviewList table table-striped table-condensed table-hover").select('tr[valign="top"]')

platform = ''
total_votes, total_score = None, None
for row in table[1:]:
    # handle cases like playstation
    if row.find('td', colspan='2', class_='center'):
        platform = row.find('td').text
        total_score, total_votes = None, None
        print('{} | {} | {} | {} | {}'.format(platform, total_votes, None, None, total_score))
        continue

    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols) == 3:
        platform = cols[0].text
        total_votes = cols[1].text
        total_score = cols[2].text
        continue
    print('{} | {} | {} | {} | {}'.format(platform, total_votes, cols[0].text, cols[1].text, total_score))
```

Output:

```
PlayStation 3 | None | None | None | None
Windows | 6 |       Acting | 4.2 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       AI | 3.7 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       Gameplay | 4.0 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       Graphics | 4.2 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       Personal Slant | 4.3 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       Sound / Music | 4.3 | 4.1
Windows | 6 |       Story / Presentation | 3.8 | 4.1
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Acting | 3.8 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       AI | 3.2 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Gameplay | 3.4 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Graphics | 3.6 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Personal Slant | 3.6 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Sound / Music | 3.4 | 3.5
Xbox 360 | 5 |       Story / Presentation | 3.8 | 3.5
```

**Note:** By *print*, I mean save those values in whatever list/DataFrame you are using. I'm just using `print()` to show how to change the `platform` variable as and when needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I asked simialr question yesterday but could not apply it to new data

Comment: Indeed, I need to scrape more than one pages, and there might be many cases like playstation, is there anyway that I can keep non values for PlayStation3 ?

Comment: Can you give an example link where such a case like playstation occurs? It'll be easier to generalize after considering multiple cases.

Comment: Have a look at the edit. If this doesn't work for any other page, please share that link.